# show a function is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$ by using power series

Tags: complex-analysis

Use power series methods to show that the function which is $\frac{\sin z}{z}  $ when $z \neq 0$ and $1$ when $z = 0$ is analytic on the whole complex plane.

Any hint on how I might approach this? The problem is every theorem I know takes it as a premise that f is analytic, so I don't know how to work the other way around (find a power series and prove that it's analytic).

I tried writing out power series expansions but then don't know how to proceed.
\begin{align*}
\sin(z) &= z- \frac{z^3}{3!} + \frac{z^5}{5!}-\cdots = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nz^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\\
\frac{\sin(z)}{z} &= 1- \frac{z^2}{3!} + \frac{z^4}{5!}-\cdots = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nz^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}
\end{align*}

Comment: Note that the second power series has an infinite radius of convergence and equals $1$ when $z=0$.

Comment: @copper.hat Sorry but what should that tell me?

Comment: That the function $z \mapsto {\sin z \over z}$ is analytic on the entire plane.

Comment: Oh great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in finding its power series representation you just demonstrated that the singularity at $z=0$ is removable, so this function is analytic on all of $\mathbb{C}$.